# Handling large log volume in rsyslog with omhttp and omfile

Tags: logging, rsyslog

In my use case, I have a service which produces large log volume and the logs must written to a file in addition to loggly (3rd party ELK as a service)

The service is configured to write json logs to port `515`

I'm seeing a problem where the logs in `service_log.jsonl` fall behind at an increasing rate once the service has been running for some time. I suspect this is due to the action queues for both `direct_service_json` and `push_loggly_service` are somehow coupled

Ideally, I'd like to completely decouple `direct_service_json` and `push_loggly_service` such that the `push_loggly_service` writer can take as long as it needs to push logs to loggly while `direct_service_json` stays up to date on the service logs

What is the best way to go about doing this? I have provided the config file I'm using - with this configuration the logs in `service_log.jsonl` start lagging behind within 30 minutes or so

```
module(load="omhttp")
module(load="mmjsonparse")
module(load="imudp")

template(name="json_logs" type="list") {
    constant(value="{")   property(name="hostname"      outname="hostname"      format="jsonfr")
    constant(value=",")   property(name="timereported"  outname="timestamp" format="jsonfr" dateFormat="rfc3339")
    constant(value=",")   property(name="programname"   outname="proc"      format="jsonfr")
    constant(value=",")   property(name="syslogpriority-text" outname="level"     format="jsonfr")
    constant(value=",")   property(name="$!all-json" position.from="2")
}

template(name="simple" type="list") {
    property(name="syslogtag")
    property(name="msg")
    constant(value="\n")
}


# Write messages to /var/log/service_logs.jsonl
ruleset(name="direct_service_json" queue.Type="LinkedList") {
        action(type="omfile" file="/var/log/service_logs.jsonl" template="simple")
}

# Send messages to Loggly using the json_logs template.
# Using two consumers to handle insane log volume
# Consumers are capped at 4, rsyslog spawns workers when action is backlogged at 100
ruleset(name="push_loggly_service" queue.Type="LinkedList" queue.WorkerThreads="4" queue.workerThreadMinimumMessages="100"){
        action(type="mmjsonparse" cookie="")
        action(type="omhttp"
                server="logs-01.loggly.com"
                errorfile="/var/log/rsyslog.error.log"
                restpath="inputs/SECRET_TOKEN/tag/rsyslog"
                retry="on"
                useHttps="on"
                template="json_logs"
                )
        }

input(type="imudp" port="515" name="json-input")

# Hack - attempt to decouple the file writer from the loggly writer
if $inputname == "json-input" then {
        call direct_service_json
}

if $inputname == "json-input" then {
        call push_loggly_service
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Per the advice from one of the head rsyslog maintainers, I successfully managed to decouple the main queue from the action queue.

I used the `impstats` module to monitor my queues as they grew to find the bottleneck.

With my config the main queue kept growing alongside the push_loggly action queue

I changed my ruleset from this

```
ruleset(name="push_loggly_service" queue.Type="LinkedList" queue.WorkerThreads="4" queue.workerThreadMinimumMessages="100"){
        action(type="mmjsonparse" cookie="")
        action(type="omhttp"
                server="logs-01.loggly.com"
                errorfile="/var/log/rsyslog.error.log"
                restpath="inputs/SECRET_TOKEN/tag/rsyslog"
                retry="on"
                useHttps="on"
                template="json_logs"
                )
        }
```

to this. I just took the queue parameters out of the ruleset and put them into the omhttp action. Apparently this creates an action queue which is decoupled from the main message queue.

```
ruleset(name="push_loggly_service"){
        action(type="mmjsonparse" cookie="")
        action(type="omhttp"
                server="logs-01.loggly.com"
                errorfile="/var/log/rsyslog.error.log"
                restpath="inputs/SECRET_TOKEN/tag/rsyslog"
                retry="on"
                useHttps="on"
                template="json_logs"
                queue.Type="LinkedList"
                queue.Size="300000"
                queue.workerthreadminimummessages="200"
                queue.workerthreads="2"
                )
        }
```

I'm okay with the omhttp queue being backlogged - as long as it doesn't slow down logging as a whole.